# FormData append list object

Tags: javascript, java, spring, form-data

Data is not passed from ajax to controller

I have the following model.

```
    @Setter
    @Getter
    public class Board {
        int bno;
        String bcontent;
        CustomUser user;
        .
        .
        .
        List<File> filevo;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    public class File { 
        int fno;
        String file_path;
    }
```

And I coded JavaScript like this:

```
    var rmvFileArr = new Array();

    function remove(fno){
        var fileObj = new Object(); 
        var src = $("#fileno"+fno+" img").attr('src');
        fileObj.fno=fno;
        fileObj.file_path=src;
        rmvFileArr.push(fileObj);
    }

    formData.append("filvo", rmvFileArr);
    for(var i =0; i<rmvFileArr.length; i++){
        formData.append("filvo["+ i +"].fno", rmvFileArr[i].fno);
        formData.append("filvo["+ i +"].file_path",
                rmvFileArr[i].file_path);
    }
    formData.append("bcontent",document.getElementById("autosize").value);
    formData.append("user.uno",document.getElementById("uno").value);
```

'array push' works just fine, like `rmvFileArr.push(fileObj)`.
I checked with the console.

```
   public String upload(@ModelAttribute Board board) throws Exception{

              .
              .
              .


     logger.info("filevo " +
                            board.getFilevo().get(0).getFno()); 
   }
```

`board.getFilevo().get(0).getFno()` causes a null point error.
All data is passed except `List<File> filevo`.
How can an array come to the controller?

Comment: Can you post your network tab request for this request as well?

Comment: omg..I'm an idiot!! I should have set the FormData key value to 'filevo'.
But I set it to 'filvo' and got an error. I wouldn't have known it without your comment. Thanks for the help !!